# Пытался сделать не большую таблицу. Решил добавить поиск по тексту

Tags: javascript, length

```
function tableSearch() {
    var phrase = document.getElementById('search-text');
    var table = document.getElementById('info-table');
    var regPhrase = new RegExp(phrase.value, 'i');
    var flag = false;
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        flag = false;
        for (var j = table.rows[i].cells.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            flag = regPhrase.test(table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
            if (flag) break;
        }
        if (flag) {
            table.rows[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            table.rows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```
table.rows.length; i++
```

пишет что функция обнулена я так понял

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: Скорее всего `document.getElementById('info-table')` ничего не нашёл. Либо нашёл что-то, у чего нет свойства `rows`. В общем, `table.rows` == `undefined` по какой-то причине.

Comment: Язык Javascript? Добавьте тег

Comment: не нашелся ваш table. И если вы скрываете строки, то проверяйте сразу всю строку - table.rows[i].innerHTML, зачем лишний цикл с ячейками.